# Sub ul not opening correctly with float:left;

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

Here's my tool, I want to create an accordion menu in the left panel: http://www.resolution-studio.ro/new/sticker/designer/

I am using accordion menu from: http://www.resolution-studio.ro/new/sticker/designer/ which works okay for sub li tags untill it does not use float:left; I want to have 80x80 pixel items so I have changed a bit the CSS code and set float to left to the a tags inside the sub ul li tags. It places it well, the problem is when I want to open it it opens then hides it.

The code uses slideToggle("normal") to open/close it.
I have tried different ways to make it work but it doesn't.

Is it a common problem I did not meet so far, or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is the following thing, like @n-dru said. You have to add a `clear:both` to your list but be careful that if you do that it will also apply on your sublist.

I think you can fix this by adding the following code:

```
.accordion li {
    list-style: none;
  text-align:left;
    clear: both;
}
.accordion li ul li{   
    clear:none;
}
.sub-menu li {
  width: 86px !important;
  float: left !important;
}
```

Due to the fact that you will add `clear:both` to your code you must add !important statements to your sub-menu li.

Let me know if this solved the problem

Comment: Thanks Pierezzz, you pointed out the problem, as it was not the clear:none the problem (as I thought) because I had not given it a clear both. The only problem was that the .sub-menu li did not have a pre-set width. I have set it to 86px and now it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Except for `float: left` add `clear: both` or `clear: left` to your `li` style definition and then adjust their width, for example `100%` to fill whole container's width..